# Java "package does not exist" error in UNIX

Tags: java, unix, package

My project directory structure is something like this: `ProjectName/coursesRegistration/src/coursesRegistration/util`
When I do `"import coursesRegistration.util.FileProcessor;`" in Eclipse it works but when I try this on UNIX (using command line compilation) it gives me an error saying

```
"error: package coursesRegistration.util does not exist".
```

Maybe I am missing something very basic, does anyone know what may be the problem?

Comment: is your class is public ?

Comment: When you run this with java command whst dir do you run it from, what is -cp switch set to? More details please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you guys! I just found out running "ant -buildfile build.xml" and then "ant run -buildfile build.xml" does the magic for you!

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to do command-line compilation, this is probably the issue.

You're running the `javac` command outside of the `src` folder. This is an issue because java's package system expects to find class `coursesRegistration.util.FileProcessor` in `./coursesRegistration/util/FileProcessor.java`, where the current directory is where you are when you run `javac`. The way to fix this is to pass the path to the `src` directory to the `--class-path` option. For example, running the compiler from the `ProjectName` directory:

```
javac --class-path coursesRegistration/src ...
```

Also, just so you know, you will have to be in the `src` directory to run the program itself. Eclipse handles all this behind the scenes, so I would either use Eclipse, or the command line, but not both.

Comment: Yes I understand but I prefer using command line to have a better learning experience.

Comment: Well, pick, since it's a pain to do both. Either command line or Eclipse. I wouldn't do both, as I said before. I'm not saying command line is bad. Also, if you really want to do both, you're welcome to.