# Getting a package does not exist error when compiling Google Cloud libraries in terminal with Java

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform

I have a java file under src/ that has the following import because I would like to use Google Cloud's translate API:

```
import com.google.cloud.translate.*;
```

I have my main method in Main.java. I have all the necessary .jar files stored in a folder called "Cloud" and in the terminal, I try to compile the code by running:

```
$ javac -cp "Cloud/*.jar" src/*.java
```

But I get the following error:

```
src/Main.java:4: error: package com.google.cloud.translate does not exist
import com.google.cloud.translate.*;
^
```

I'm not sure why since I imported all the dependencies and set the classpath. It all works when I run the program in the IDE Eclipse, but it doesn't when I try to compile it in the terminal. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

I will post my comment as an answer as it is too long for the comment section.

When checking the [official documentation regarding the Translating API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/basic/translating-text#translating_text), it is stated before trying to use it to follow the [Translation Quickstart Using Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/basic/setup-basic) for the set-up process, as it might help.

Additionally, I stumbled across [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52357602/java-package-does-not-exist-error-in-unix) indicating that the issue could lay on running the javac command outside of the src folder.

I hope this information helps.